# Adding an external <script> with data parameters after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, attr

I need to add a < script > tag with external src and with data-*="" parameters inside a < form >. It is ok if you just add it in page. But if I do it after an ajax request, script reports it can't find data- parameters, and it is outside needed html elements.

I read that jQuery on .append() somehow rearranges < script > tags, and put them in the end (outside needed elements), and looses data- attributes.

Is there any other way to append a script after ajax request with needed data- parameters?

```
I tried 
$('<script>').attr(/*all data params*/)
```

but it does not work.
Please help

Comment: *"I need to call a < script > tag with data-*="" parameters."* You don't "call" script tags. What do you mean by that? Create/add them? Find them (already on the page)? Or...? *"...somehow rearranges < script > tags..."* What script tags? From where? Once a script tag is in the page, rearranging it makes no sense. Please update your question with a more thorough description of what you need to do, with examples of the content you're working with, being clear about the actual end goal and starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you get the result from your Ajax request in the right place. As this is an asynchronous operation, it might be that you're data parameters are not populated at all.

The following code sends a request when you click the button and gets the result in the callback function :

```
function callback(data) {
  // Got result from AJAX, play with DOM + jQuery here
  console.log("callback called, data : ", data);
  $("#callbackResultId").html(JSON.stringify(data));
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#textAjaxButtonId").click(function(){
    $.ajax({ 
      url: '/echo/json',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        json: JSON.stringify({
          'attr': 'value'
         })
        },
      success: function(data, status, xhr){  
        callback(data);
      }
    });
  })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uemaft67/

The callback function is the place where you would get your Ajax response, and therefore build the DOM nodes along with the needed attributes.

Hope this helps!